# Why should I only pick the positive number for $C$ in this IVP (separable differential equation)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm practicing some problems for an upcoming DEs test. I tried the following initial value problem:

> $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{y+1}\cos x,y(\pi)=0$

Here's my work:

$\begin{align}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}&=\sqrt{y+1}\cos x \\
\int\displaystyle\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y+1}}&=\int 2\cos x\,dx \\
2\sqrt{y+1}&=2\sin x+c_1 \\
\sqrt{y+1}&=\sin x + C \\
y+1&=(\sin x + C)^2
\end{align}$

Plugging in the initial value I get:

$\begin{align}
0+1&=(\sin\pi+C)^2\\
C^2&=1 \\
C&=\pm 1
\end{align}$

So the final answer I got was $y=(\sin x \pm 1)^2-1$, but the solution in the textbook was $y=(\sin x +1)^2-1$. Why did they only pick $+1$ as an answer for $C$?

Comment: Ah, I think I see why! Is it because of the step $\sqrt{y+1}=\sin x +C$? Since the square root function's range is strictly positive, we have to make sure the RHS of this step is strictly positive as well. Since $-1\leq \sin x \leq 1$, $-2\leq \sin x - 1 \leq 0$ which falls outside of the range of the square root function. Is that why?

Comment: It's also worth noting that $0\leq \sin x +1 \leq 2$, meaning this does fall within the range of the square root function.

Comment: yes, @blakedylanmusic you've already found the answer. You can also set the value of the constant $C$ before squaring both sides of the equation, and only one value for $C$ would be true. (That's also a good thing to do before apllying inverse functions that have injectivity issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that since $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2\sqrt{y+1}\cos(x)$ is a function which is continuous on an open subset of the domain of $f(x)=2\sqrt{y+1}\cos(x)$ containing the point $(\pi,0)$ and so is $\partial f/\partial y$, we are guaranteed that there exists a unique solution containing the point $(\pi,0)$. So it cannot be the case that both $y=(\sin(x)+1)^2+1$ and $y=(\sin(x)-1)^2+1$ are solutions.
Both functions satisfy the initial condition in that the point $(\pi,0)$ lies on the graphs of both.

Consider the choice C=1.

Let $y=(\sin(x)+1)^2-1=\sin^2(x)+2\sin(x)$
\begin{eqnarray}\frac{dy}{dx}&=&2\sin(x)\cos(x)+2\cos(x)\\
\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy}{dx}&=&(\sin(x)+1)\cos(x)\\
 &=& |\sin(x)+1|\cos(x)\\
&=&\sqrt{\sin^2(x)-2\sin(x)+1}\cos(x)\\
&=&\sqrt{y+1}\cos(x)\end{eqnarray}

Now, consider the choice $C=-1$.

Let $y=(\sin(x)-1)^2-1$

Then \begin{eqnarray}\frac{dy}{dx}&=&2\sin(x)\cos(x)-2\cos(x)\\
\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy}{dx}&=&(\sin(x)-1)\cos(x)\\
 &=& -|\sin(x)-1|\cos(x)\\
&=&-\sqrt{\sin^2(x)-2\sin(x)+1}\cos(x)\\
&=&-\sqrt{y+1}\cos(x)\end{eqnarray}

Which does not satisfy the differential equation.

Comment: Yikes, I see that I accidentally deleted part of the answer. Let me fix it.

Comment: You need to raise the first "continuous" to "continuously differentiable" to get the existence of a unique solution.

Comment: Ah, I see! Doesn’t the existence and uniqueness theorem also say that $\partial f/\partial y$ must be continuous at the initial value $(\pi,0)$?

Comment: In this case $\partial f/\partial y = \cos x/\sqrt{y+1}$ which is defined at $(\pi,0)$ so that would certainly also help show there exists a unique solution.

Comment: @blakedylanmusic My DE book is packed away somewhere, but from memory I believe it is continuous and differentiable on an open neighborhood of the initial value point. Oh, and yes, you are right about $\partial f/\partial y$.

Comment: Yes, I think my book says $f$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ must be continuous and differentiable in some rectangle $R$ around the initial value point.